# What are golgi blobs?

Tags: cell-biology, mitosis

From a general google search I have come to know that golgi 'blobs'(also referred to as "*golgi haze*") are tubular vesicles formed during the interphase of mitosis. 
I would like to be reassured and also learn more about this topic. If possible please include a diagram in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**What are golgi?**

- Stacked array in the cisternae which are ought to connect vesicles and tubules
- Made of >1000 different proteins
- Has the ability to transform/alter in response to a cellular stimulation such as mitosis

**Fragmentation of golgi during mitosis**

> During interphase, the Golgi receives secretory cargo from the ER via the COP II vesicle formation pathway. Depending on their nature, secretory cargo then travel through the Golgi apparatus by a combination of vesicular transport involving COP I vesicles and cisternal maturation. A retrograde COP I vesicle pathway connects Golgi cisternae and the ER to allow recycling of Golgi enzymes and integral membrane proteins of the transport machinery such as the SNAREs. Two models have been proposed to explain the fate of the Golgi in mitosis. The first is the direct fragmentation model, where Golgi cisternae are consumed by continued COP I vesicle budding in the absence of membrane fusion, which is blocked in mitosis. This generates a pool of tubules and vesicles (Golgi haze) containing Golgi enzymes and structural proteins. The second is the ER recycling model, where forward transport into the Golgi by COP II vesicles is blocked, but COP I recycling back to the ER continues until Golgi proteins are redistributed to this compartment. Some Golgi proteins may then exit the ER via the COP II pathway, but these vesicles are unable to fuse with a Golgi compartment during mitosis, and remain in equilibrium with the ER.

A more detailed outline of the process of fragmentation of golgi apparatus can be found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2175146/) and [here](http://www.cbi.pku.edu.cn/chinese/documents/cell/xibaoshengwuxuecankaowenxian/cocb/15/15-4/15-462.pdf)

[image: golgi fragmentation during mitosis]

As I know "*golgi blobs*" are also referred to as "*golgi haze*".

*Sources:*

1. http://www.clfs.umd.edu/classroom/mocb639/Hamza_Golgi_Apr5_2005.pdf
2. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2175146/
3. http://www.cbi.pku.edu.cn/chinese/documents/cell/xibaoshengwuxuecankaowenxian/cocb/15/15-4/15-462.pdf

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh You're welcome. Let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Comment: Golgi blobs are larger fragments and are resolvable by light microscope.  The golgi haze is not resolvable and just causes scattering of light in the microscope as if it were a fog.